# Find $\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x^{15} - 3^{15} - 15 \cdot 3^{14}(x-3)}{(x-3)^2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Please help me find:

> $$
> \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x^{15} - 3^{15} - 15 \cdot 3^{14}(x-3)}{(x-3)^2}
> $$

I cannot use L'Hospital's rule.

I tried to eliminate $x-3$, but I have no idea what to do next.
$$
\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x^{15} - 3^{15} - 15 \cdot 3^{14}(x-3)}{(x-3)^2} = 
\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x^{14} + 3x^{13} + ... + 3^{14} - 15 \cdot 3^{14}}{x-3}
$$

Comment: You won't like it, but you probably need to eliminate $x-3$ again.

Comment: @player3236 Wow, I'm shocked actually

Comment: I believe we have reach a consensus and the "probably" in my first comment can be removed.

Comment: My mistake was typing $x-3$ instead of $(x-3)^2$ into Desmos. zwim has got the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=3+u$ with $u\to 0$ then use binomial formula to expand $(3+u)^{15}$.

You can ignore terms in $u^k$ with $k\ge 3$ because when divided by $u^2$ they converge to $0$.

$\require{cancel}\begin{align}f(x)&=\dfrac{(3+u)^{15}-3^{15}-15\cdot3^{14}u}{u^2}\\\\&=\dfrac{\bigg(\cancel{3^{15}}+\cancel{15\cdot3^{14}u}+\binom{15}{2}3^{13}u^2+o(u^2)\bigg)-\cancel{3^{15}}-\cancel{15\cdot3^{14}u}}{u^2}\\\\&=3^{13}\times\frac{14\times15}{2}+o(1)\to 35\times 3^{14}\end{align}$

Comment: Nice workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Now, $$\frac{x^{14}+3x^{13}+...+3^{13}x-14\cdot3^{14}}{x-3}=\frac{x^{14}-3^{14}}{x-3}+3\cdot\frac{x^{13}-3^{13}}{x-3}+...+3^{13}\rightarrow$$
$$=14\cdot3^{13}+3\cdot13\cdot3^{12}+...+3^{13}=(14+13+...+1)3^{13}=105\cdot3^{13}=35\cdot3^{14}.$$
I used the following:
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)$$  for natural $n\geq2$.

We see that in the big  brackets we have $n$ terms $a^n$ for $a=b$.

Comment: It should say $35 \cdot 3^{14}$ at the very end.

Comment: @Toby Mak  I don't agree. zwim made a typo.

Comment: Your method is correct, but $14 + 13 + 12$ is already $39$, so it cannot be $35 \cdot 3^{13}$.

Comment: @Toby Mak  Now I see. I fixed. Thank you!